# How to migrate D365 Business Units and their default teams and keep GUIDs

Tags: dynamics-crm-365

I've been trying to migrate some BUs and their default teams from our dev environment to a higher environment and keep the default teams' GUIDs the same in both envs but have not been successful. I tried changing the order I deploy them, ie tried deploying BUs before and after teams but it made no difference. The problem is when I deploy a BU, the system automatically creates a default team which I cannot delete or rename or even make non-default so that I could make the teams I want (with the same GUID) as default. Also I've tried different tools such as SDK's DataMigrationUtility and XrmToolBox's Data Transporter but the outcome is the same, i.e. I cannot get rid of the default team.

I would appreciate any advice on how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Default Teams for BU are created by system automatically and you cannot transfer them or create them or unassigned them.

Same is the case with default queue for Team (owner Team) you cannot create them, transfer them and unassigned them.

You could definitely transfer Teams (which are not default teams) but unfortunately the one you are trying is not possible.

Comment: Hi AnkUser. Thanks for your response. In that case, we always end up with BUs having different GUIDs for their default teams in different environments. So how do we ensure we use the same default teams (with the same GUIDs) for BUs in different envs so that we keep them in sync?